# Xdebug and PhpStorm with Laravel Sail debugs server.php only

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-sail

I installed the latest Laravel (`curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`) with SAIL.

In my `.env` I added:

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug,profile
```

When I set the "Break at first line in php scripts" setting in PhpStorm, the script stops at the `server.php` file. The generated `cachegrind.out.21` file contains the `server.php` only as well.

What do I need to do, to debug the original code instead of the `server.php` only?

In PhpStorm in the servers settings I added the host `localhost:80` and I mapped the project files to the `/var/www/html` dir.

When I remove the "stop at first line" setting and add a breakpoint in the `public/index.php` instead, it is not stopping at all. To verify, I tried the debugging in VSCode and it is stopping in the `index.php`.

In addition what I found (and don't understand), when I remove the server config from phpstorm and reload the browser, a window "Incoming Connection From Xdebug" appears. The mentioned file path on server is `/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php`. But basically this ends up in my configuration that I already had.

As from the comments, I enabled logging:

```
[26] Log opened at 2023-06-05 10:03:18.607155
[26] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[26] [Config] INFO: No shared secret: Activating
[26] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[26] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[26] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.2.6" protocol_version="1.0" appid="26" idekey="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"><engine version="3.2.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 8 -c 1
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="8" success="1"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- status -i 9
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="9" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 10
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="10" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="string" size="7" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MC4wLjAuMA==]]></property></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODA=]]></property></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 15 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="15"><property type="string" size="12" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2Zhdmljb24uaWNv]]></property></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 16
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="16"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php" lineno="3"></stack></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- run -i 17
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="17" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[26] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 18
[26] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="18" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[26] Log closed at 2023-06-05 10:03:18.701446
```

This is how the config looks like:
[image]

When I remove it and reload the browser, I get:
[image]
I accept it and add `/var/www/html` in the paths later on.

Comment: *"When I set the "Break at first line in php scripts" setting in PhpStorm..."* + *"What do I need to do, to debug the original code instead of the server.php only?"* Disable that option. Because it does exactly what you have asked -- it stops at the first line. You are using Laravel's web server where `server.php` is used as an entry script. Set breakpoints where you need them.

Comment: When I disable it, and add a breakpoint in `index.php` instead, it is not stopping at all. When I do the same in VSC, then it stops.

Comment: Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it will have to say -- does PhpStorm sets any breakpoints, what path is used etc. That's the starting point. If it sets no breakpoints then perhaps it does not see the matching paths... Anyway: you can also enable extra logging on PhpStorm end and see what it thinks about it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collecting-logs

Comment: It connects just fine But I see no breakpoints attempted. Something is missing / configured wrong. Please show the screenshots of 1) the URL you are calling 2) your `Settings | PHP | Servers` entry (the server names and path mappings) 3) The file where the breakpoints are (make sure it shows the file path). Maybe you are setting the breakpoint in the wrong file (wrong path or unused in this request file)

Comment: But before that: delete your current `Settings | PHP | Servers` entry and try to debug -- the IDE should show that popup screen and will help creating one. Maybe you have entered something wrong in the first place (it happens on manual creation, ppl are putting the wrong stuff thinking it works differently).

Comment: That did the trick! Apparently, I can't see any noticeable difference in the server setting, but now it's stopping at the correct breakpoint. Still, what I finally want to accomplish is profiling and the `cachegrind.out.XX` file stills shows the `server.php` only.

Comment: *"That did the trick! Apparently, I can't see any noticeable difference in the server setting"* If you show a screenshot of that (whatever you have: only current or both) then I should be able to give some hint. My best guess thus far: wrong host was entered. In regards to profiling: not sure on that at all -- never tried to profile an app running under Sail. I also have not really used PhpStorm's tool to view the cechegrind output files (used another stuff).

Comment: P.S. If you want to profile then you do not need the debug mode (AFAIK as it should be making things slower hence showing the wrong values)

Comment: I attached the screenshot

Comment: *"In PhpStorm in the servers settings I added the host `localhost:80` and I mapped the project files to the `/var/www/html` dir."* 1) So as I understand you had `localhost:80` in the host field in the first place and now it's `0.0.0.0` (whatever PhpStorm detects as a Server Name that the webserver/PHP reports and what a user would expect to enter there manually).

Comment: 2) The path mapping seems good -- normally you just map the remove project root to a local project root and it will inherit it for all subfolders. Extra mappings might be needed if some paths are symlinks or located outside of the local project (since Xdebug works with final/resolved remote paths while PhpStorm uses local path as is).

Comment: Any idea on how to fix the profiling?

Comment: In regards to profiling: not sure on that at all -- never tried to profile an app running under Sail. I also have not really used PhpStorm's tool to view the cechegrind output files (used another stuff). Maybe you are viewing the results in a wrong way and only see the entry stuff (I very doubt about it but just double check it)... Anyway, try `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=profile` with `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` -- this should profile every single request automatically. Maybe it will yield some different results...

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page because of the same problem. I read the comments, looked at the server logs and realized what the problem was. The fact is that by default, xDebug uses `cachegrind.out.%p` as the profile file name, where `%p` is the process ID, however, the Laravel server uses one process and by default the profile file is overwritten each time.

My browser, for example, makes a request to favicon.ico, which erases the profile results:
[image: Application logs]

Therefore, you need to change the name of the output file to `cachegrind.out.%r` to end as a random hexadecimal number, or use `cachegrind.out.%R` to use the request uri as file parameter. To learn how to change the profile file name and what file name options are available, visit the documentation site: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler#profiler_output_name

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on my `Laravel Sail` installation.
The xdebugger was only caught on: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php` and nothing else.

**I made it work** (for debug mode at least) by adding a mapping entry of `/var/www/html` next to project folder root:

[image]